# Quick question about cup products

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image]

How can we say that this cup product is $0$? I can't think of the justification. Is it that $$\theta \smile \theta \in H^4(S^2) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $\theta \in H^2(S^2)$ so $\theta^2 \in H^4(S^2) \cong 0$, therefore for $i = 1, 2$ the product $p_i^*(\theta)^2$ is $0$ by naturality of the cup product.

This is easy to conceptualize with the commutative diagram representing naturality:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H^2(S^2)\otimes H^2(S^2) @>{\cup}>> H^4(S^2) \cong 0\\
@V{p_i^*\otimes p_i^*}VV @V{p_i^*}VV\\
H^2(S^2 \times S^2) \otimes H^2(S^2\times S^2) @>{\cup}>> H^4(S^2 \times S^2)
\end{CD}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are right, $\theta \smile \theta \in H^4(S^2) = 0$. However, it is useful to know that the cup product in the cohomology ring $H^*(\Sigma X)$ of a suspension $\Sigma X$ is trivial. See [cup product in cohomology ring of a suspension](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1298938). This applies to $S^2 = \Sigma S^1$.