# Proof that $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is not the suspension of a space $X$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

I am looking to prove that $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\Sigma X$ for any space $X$, where $\Sigma$ denotes suspension of a space. I am stumpted as the context of the question is homology, and while homology is homeomorphism invariant, it's certainly not the case that non-homeo. spaces must have different homology groups. If I suppose that there is a space $X$ satisfying this requirement, what other properties must $\Sigma X$ that $\mathbb{RP}^2$ does not to achieve a contradiction?

My only other thought so far is that $H_2(\mathbb{RP^2})=0$, which might be interesting... but as I can make no assumptions about $X$, I can't see why $\Sigma X$ must have a non-trivial second homology group.

Comment: If you know co-homology, then you can use that the cup product in any suspension is trivial.

Comment: I do know cohomology, but not this fact - is there an 'obvious' reason why it's true?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298938/cup-product-in-cohomology-ring-of-a-suspension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduced homology of a space $X$ and its suspension are related by $\tilde{H}_n(X)\simeq\tilde{H}_{n+1}(\Sigma X)$. Now $\tilde{H}_0(X)$ is always torsion-free but $\tilde{H}_1(\mathbb{RP}^2)\simeq\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so $\mathbb{RP}^2$ cannot be homeomorphic to $\Sigma X$.